# Passenger: failed to compile Apache 2 module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-ec2, passenger

I tried installing passenger on AWS for rails and got through the tutorial I was following. At the end I was having an issue so I uninstalled passenger. However, now I am unable to re-install. It gets stuck compiling Apache 2. I'd appreciate any ideas. I also tried doing rm -rf* on the folders it mentioned it couldn't remove and it didn't seem to work. Thanks for any help!

```
Checking whether there are multiple Apache installations...
Only a single installation detected. This is good.

--------------------------------------------
Compiling and installing Apache 2 module...
cd /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/passenger-5.1.7
# env NOEXEC_DISABLE=1 /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/wrappers/rake RELEASE=yes apache2:clean apache2
rm -rf buildout/cache
rm -rf buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a buildout/common/libboost_oxt
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/regex_raw_buffer.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/regex.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/regex_debug.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/cregex.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/regex_traits_defaults.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/once.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/posix_api.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/once_atomic.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/c_regex_traits.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/tss_null.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/static_mutex.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/future.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/thread.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/winstances.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/cpp_regex_traits.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/error_code.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/wide_posix_api.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/wc_regex_traits.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/instances.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/oxt/implementation.o’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘buildout/common/libboost_oxt/oxt/system_calls.o’: Permission denied
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [rm -rf buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a buil...]
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/passenger-5.1.7/build/common_library.rb:88:in `block in define_libboost_oxt_task'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => apache2:clean => common:clean
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: rvm implode then start over from the point of installing rvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has to do with your user permissions, try this :

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

If you get the `Command not found error` check the solution [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/troubleshooting/ruby/#i-get-command-not-found-when-running-a-passenger-command-through-sudo).